# Store multiple arrays inside objects?

Tags: javascript, html

In the past, i've created a function, to get multiple Node list's properties. Then, with the properties create visual effets. It looks like this:

```js
var elem, celElem, elemTop = [],
  elemMag = [],
  elemBot = [],
  elemCent = [],
  winTop, winMag, winBot, winCent, i, x, len, elemCsokk = [],
  elemNo = [],
  elemCentValt = [],
  elemCentWinCent = [];

function getElem(el, cEl, fn) {
  if (el.length === undefined) {
    el = [el];
    cEl = [cEl];
  }
  elem = el;
  celElem = cEl;
  winTop = window.pageYOffset;
  winMag = window.innerHeight;
  winBot = winTop + winMag;
  winCent = winTop + (winMag / 2);
  for (i = 0, len = elem.length; i < len; i++) {
    elemTop[i] = 0;
    elemMag[i] = elem[i].offsetHeight;
    elemBot[i] = 0;
    elemCent[i] = 0;
    elemCsokk[i] = 0;
    topMag(elem[i]);
    fn(i);
  }

}

function topMag(y) {
  x = y;
  do {
    elemTop[i] += x.offsetTop;
    x = x.offsetParent;
  }
  while (x !== document.body);
  x = y;

  elemBot[i] = elemTop[i] + elemMag[i];
  elemCent[i] = elemTop[i] + (elemMag[i] / 2);
  elemCsokk[i] = (elemBot[i] - winTop) / winMag;

}

function opaCsokk(i) {
  elem[i].style.opacity = elemCsokk[i];
}

var element = document.querySelectorAll("div")

window.onscroll = function() {
  getElem(element, element, opaCsokk)
}
```

The function works really well, the only problem is, that executing the function every time a scroll happens causes performance issues. So i decided that i rethink the function. What i need to get on every scroll are the properties of the window `(winTop, winMag, winCent, winBot)`. The properties of the elements aren't changing. What i'm thinking about is that i can create a big array (replacement of the `getElem` function), storing the node lists and the properties of them. In this way the above example looks like this (getting the `elemMag` of the first node in the node list):
`bigArray[0]["elemMag"][0]`
with the function:

```js
var bigArray = [];

function addingToBigArray(elem) {
  var element = elem;
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    bigArray[bigArray.length] = {
      elemMag[i]: element.offsetHeight,
      elemTop[i]: element.offsetTop
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunately an object's property can't be an array. How can i solve this problem, to get the same result of the above example with the function `getElem`?

Comment: "an object's property can't be an array" — that is totally false. Do you mean "an object's property *name* can't be an array"?

Comment: if you're up to date with javascript, try: `{ [elemMag[i]]: element.offsetHeight}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bigArray = [];

function addingToBigArray(elem) {
  var element = elem;
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    bigArray[bigArray.length] = {
      [elemMag[i]]: element.offsetHeight
    }
  }
}
```

---

See: [[]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Thanks! Here's a problem for me. The solution works, but inside the object, with a property, i can't use another properties values. A simplier example:
`var x = {
    first = [0, 1],
    second = x.first[0]+1
}`
It doesn't work. :/

Comment: that isnt a valid javascript object declaration

Comment: I can't access a property's value with another property in the same object?